# Syncing script makes gui slow in IOS app swift

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a method that will sync my app with the online API. When running this sync script the reponses of the app are delayed. I tried using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), { 
 self.syncEverything() 
}
```

This doesn't has any effect on the speed. Could someone tell me the right approach for this problem?

**EDIT**

I changed the code, my syncing script is now using a different context then the context of the main thread. When the syncing is complete, I merge the contexts. Still the syncing is slowing down the gui.

Below my CPU activity when syncing, does this mean everything is running on the main thread?

[image]

In some of the classes used in "syncEverything()" is UIKit imported, could this be the cause of the delay?

Comment: What does `syncEverything()` do? If anything in `syncEverything()` updates the UI then performance will be terrible or crash.

Comment: It does a lot of JSON parsing and it updates core data objects. At the end it calls: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("finished", object: nil)
.

Comment: Multithreaded Core Data get complicated. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657437/core-data-background-context-best-practice

Comment: As a simpler alternative, you can switch to [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) for all your Core Data needs. It has simple [background thread handling](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/wiki/Working-with-Managed-Object-Contexts).

Comment: I changed the code, my syncing script is now using a different context then the context of the main thread. When the syncing is complete, I merge the contexts. Still the syncing is slowing down the gui. Any suggestions?

Comment: Again, without seeing `syncEverything()`, I can't say why, but the graph you shown above has almost all of the activity on the main thread.