# Why might Core Data fail to merge data from private context to main context?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an application using Core Data with the following, fairly standard, managed object context hierarchy:

```
Persistent Store Coordinator 
    ↳ Save Context (Private Queue Concurrency Type) 
        ↳ Main Context (Main Queue Concurrency Type)
        ↳ Private Context (Private Queue Concurrency Type)
```

The merge policy for all managed object contexts is set to `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy`

I am observing `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` which will invoke the following function when the Private Context is saved and merge changes to the Main Context:

```
func contextDidSaveNotificationHandler(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let savedContext = notification.object as? NSManagedObjectContext {
        if savedContext == privateObjectContext {

            mainObjectContext.performBlock({

                if let updatedObjects = notification.userInfo![NSUpdatedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> {
                    //
                    // fire faults on the updated objects
                    //
                    for obj in updatedObjects {
                        mainObjectContext.objectWithID(obj.objectID).willAccessValueForKey(nil)
                    }
                }

                mainObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is working most of the time but sometimes I am finding that changes to existing objects in the Private Context are not being merged into the Main Context. I can't figure out why -- the private context save is successful; the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` notification is being sent; the notification handler is being invoked; `notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]` contains the correctly updated objects; but at the end, the main context is not synchronized with the private context. (ie: the managed objects in the main context are not in sync with the values contained in `notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]`) If I kill the app and relaunch it, the contexts become synchronized again (after loading objects from the persistent store).

I have `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` enabled in my launch arguments, and all Core Data multithreading rules are being followed. I can't see anything overtly wrong with my managed object context hierarchy or the merging function. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: Try https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: how are you testing that the managed objects in the main context are not in sync?

Comment: If you are only supporting iOS 10+ then you could use automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent which will deal with this for you.

Comment: in the line `if savedContext == privateObjectContext {` is `privateObjectContext` the parent of the main context or the sibling?

Comment: I am testing that they are out of sync by logging the objects (using `mainObjectContext.objectWithID(_:)`) before and after calling `mainObjectContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)`. I'm also logging the `notification.userInfo?[NSUpdatedObjectsKey]` values since those represent the state of the objects in the private context. And privateObjectContext is the sibling of the main context

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a similar structure as yours, but it wasn't reliable in my case. Sometimes it did work, sometimes it didn't. One of the errors was "incomplete merges", just like you described. I started observing this behavior in iOS 10. I believe something may have change on Core Data's core.

Anyway, I changed my approach. I started using the Apple's sample code on Core Data / Concurrency at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW3

If you read the entire page (it isn't that big), you may notice that they suggest creating a private queue, as usual, but then:

> This example can be further simplified when using an
>   NSPersistentContainer:

```
let jsonArray = …
let container = self.persistentContainer
container.performBackgroundTask() { (context) in
    for jsonObject in jsonArray {
        let mo = EmployeeMO(context: context)
        mo.populateFromJSON(jsonObject)
    }
    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Of course I'm not sure if the above code fits in your requirements exactly. However the key thing there is to rely on the `persistentContainer` to do the heavy lifting.

> After all of the data has been consumed and turned into
>   NSManagedObject instances, you call save on the private context, which
>   moves all of the changes into the main queue context without blocking
>   the main queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't merge sibling context.  You have to merge from the parent down. In other words change

```
 if savedContext == privateObjectContext {
```

to

```
 if savedContext == savingObjectContext {
```

where the `savingObjectContext` is the parent context of the main context.

Comment: What makes you say that sibling contexts can't be merged? Is there a piece of documentation you can cite to back that up? This answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663533 shows two common managed object context hierarchies where data is merged between siblings.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set your mainQueueContext as your privateQueueContext's parent:

```
privateObjectContext.parent = mainObjectContext
```

This will merge your saves into your main object context.  I used this in a project where I parse JSON, and set core data objects in a privateQueue's perform block, with my mainContext set as the parent.  Then I simple save the private, and then access the data from the main thread/main context.  Works like a charm.  I should add I do not keep the private context in memory, it is created new when I need it.

Comment: It's true that this works, but it's non-ideal from a performance standpoint because all data fetching and saving back to the persistent store done from the private object context must be 'pulled'/'pushed' through the main queue context.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your merge policy. Try changing to to NSErrorMergePolicy and I think you will start to see merge conflicts. At the least this will give you more of an idea of the underlying cause

Comment: I have tried changing the merge policy on all managed object contexts to NSErrorMergePolicy but I'm not encountering any errors when saving from either of the private queue contexts.