# CoreData delete object in context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

## Question:

- Does deleting an `NSManagedObject` have to be done with in `context.perform` / `context.performAndWait` block ?
- Or is it safe to delete the object outside the block ?

## Code:

```
func delete(something: NSManagedObject, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    context.performAndWait { //Is context.perform / context.performAndWait required to delete an object ?

        context.delete(something)
    }
}
```

## My thoughts:

- Since this code was being called from different threads (both background / main ) it was better to use `context.perform` / `context.performAndWait`.
- The context might have been created with a specific concurrent type (main / private queue).
- The context's concurrent type would need to match that of the thread (main / background) in which the code was being executed.
- The block would ensure it runs ok even if a thread with a different mismatched thread type is executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my personal experience, use `performAndWait`, because it will wait until operation done. Anyway, both method will run on it's own thread.(context's thread).

[From Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext)

> perform(*:) and performAndWait(*:) ensure the block operations are
>   executed on the queue specified for the context. The perform(*:)
>   method returns immediately and the context executes the block methods
>   on its own thread. With the performAndWait(*:) method, the context
>   still executes the block methods on its own thread, but the method
>   doesn’t return until the block is executed.

Comment: The question is not about whether to use `perform` or `performAndWait`. The question is should I use it at all or is it ok to delete without the block. I understand both would run on their respective threads, but the context might have been created with a specific concurrent type (main / private queue). My thought was context's concurrent type would need to match that of the thread (main / background).

Comment: I think you didn't understand. Ok let me explain. If you call `perform(:)` or `performAndWait(:)`, these method will place the execution block on the context's queue. Here no matter, where you calling from. If you call it from main/ background thread, that's not mean, the operation will place accordingly. It's a matter, context was created with what type. You no need to think about thread safe. It depends only on context's type.

Comment: I've seen your updated question. Third and fourth point is wrong understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. In apple documentation it is being said about „...andWait” it works assyncronious.
   However „...andWait” should be used to catch the errors inside of perform block...

   Moc.performBlock{
   for jsonObject in jsonArray {
   let your = actions
   }
   do { 
   try moc.save()

   moc.performBlockAndWait {
   do { try moc.save() } 
   catch { fatalError(„Failure to save context: (error)”) }
   }
   }...
2. Better to do it inside in case you have different values / unused values. In most cases ARC (memory management) should fix it.

You should also read here:

> [Core Data background context best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657437/core-data-background-context-best-practice)